# SSH connection rejected with public key registered

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote server via ssh.

- I'm using my `id_rsa` public key, which I already use to connect to GitHub and Bitbucket
- Accessed the server via the dashboard of the provider, and added the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Got back to my computer and tried to `ssh user@ip` and got a `user@ip: Permission denied (publickey)`
- So, `ssh user@ip -v` returns the following (last lines):

  ```
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:blablablabla /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  user@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
  ```

Also: local `id_rsa.pub` permissions are 600, server's `.ssh/` is 700 and server's `authorized_keys` is 744

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reads to me as if it tried your key, but it was then rejected:

```
user@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Re-add your key and see if that's it. If not, add more -v's (as per man page):

```
-v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication,
        and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

Comment: It's been 4 hours looking into this and the key in authorized_keys was wrong the whole time.
Thanks!